# Spring-MVC: Send a Response after a POST method

Tags: spring-mvc, post, request, response, swagger

I'm using Spring-MVC and I'm trying to send back a response body after a POST request.. It seems that Spring-MVC is sending something back but it's empty..

First question: Is it possible to send a json response after a POST request?

Second question: If yes, do I have to include some specific headers?

Thanks in advance

**The code**

```
  @CrossOrigin
  @ApiOperation(value = "Update an application", notes = "Update a document given its id. If a field is let empty, the value will not be updated.", response = Application.class)
  @ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Request could not be authorized."),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error."),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Malformed request.") })
  @RequestMapping(value = "/update",
    produces = { "application/json" },
    consumes = { "application/json", "text/json" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<Application> updateApplication(@ApiParam(value = "ID of the document", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "docId", required = true) String docId,
@RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "Additional data given to the application"  ) ApplicationData data)
      throws NotFoundException {

        ApplicationControllerMock dummyClass = new ApplicationControllerMock();

        ResponseEntity<Application> dummyResponse = dummyClass.updateApplication(docId, data);

        return dummyResponse;

  }
```

The class `Application` is a class generated by swagger-codegen.. If I use it with a GET method, it just returns me a JSON object..

**Print dummyResponse**

If I print the variable `dummyResponse`, I get this:

```
<200 OK,class Application {
  docId: cdb226df5398f564173db460b52f40de
  companyId: 123
  projectId: 123
  rev: 2-fce2134de32fae95cee4192debef4600
  docType: 3
  docCreated: 2015-09-01T02:30:14Z
  docDeleted: false
  data: class ApplicationData {
  status: string
  domain: string
  name: string
  version: string
  gaCode: string
}

  id: a2cf532b721eedb542e884820b180b55
}
,{Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=[true], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Access-Control-Allow-Methods=[GET, OPTIONS, POST, HEAD], Access-Control-Allow-Headers=[Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept], Content-Type=[application/json], Access-Control-Max-Age=[3600]}>
```

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: I edited my post to add the code.. I can't show you the whole code because it's really big and automatically generated..

Comment: did you verify if `dummyResponse` is not null?

Comment: It's not empty.. I edit the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.. The `@CrossOrigin` creates automatically these two headers:

- "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
- "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"

Since I was also adding them manually, these two headers appears twice.. Therefore, I just had to remove them and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send back a Response when the request is a POST.

You don't have to add any specific headers.